# Mean of input based on acf of filtered output

Tags: filters, autocorrelation

By looking at the ACF of the output of a filter whose impulse response I know, can I approximate the mean of the input?

For example

```
x = randn(1000,1);
y1=filter(ones(5,1),[1],x);
y2=filter(ones(5,1),[1],x + 0.2);
res1 = xcorr(y1,'unbiased');
res2 = xcorr(y2,'unbiased');
```

When I plot `res1` and `res2` it is clear `res2` has an identical shape but shifted up. This makes me think that just by looking at the ACF I can tell which process has more 'DC' but is there a way to quantify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Mathematically, the limiting value of the autocorrelation function $R_X(\tau)$ of a wide-sense-stationary process is $$\lim_{\tau\to\infty}R_X(\tau) = \lim_{\tau\to-\infty}R_X(\tau) = \mu_X^2$$ where $\mu_X$ is the mean of the process. So it is not too surprising that `res1` and `res2` have identical shapes but `res2` is shifted upwards in comparison to `res1` and the above equation tells you how much the shift is.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that practically finding this mean would be impossible as xcorr actually gets more and more unreliable as `\tau` increases ?